# How can a mount command fail in one terminal window, but not in another?

Tags: osx

On MacOSX 10.10.5, I opened a Terminal window, and did this:

`mount -t smbfs //accountname:password@server/path ./localdir`

and I got this error:

`mount_smbfs: mount error: /Users/accountname/localdir: Operation not supported by device`

This had been working the day before on the same computer. Leaving that terminal window open, I opened another. In the second window, the command works.

I have double checked, the folder was not already mounted in the other window. I can do `umount ./localdir` in the second window, and it works. Afterward, the `mount` command still fails in the first window, but works in the second.

The reason this is a problem is that we got the same error from the command when executing it in a bash script in a Jenkins build, run under the same accountname.

Where should I be looking for the problem here?

Comment: Both terminal sessions are in the same local directory, such that they can both see a useful result from `ls -ld localdir`?

Comment: Yes, these commands report the same thing. And `ls` of what's inside localdir also turn up the same results in both windows.

Comment: I know little of the possible macOS-specific intricacies of permissions, but does `id` show the same group memberships in both terminal windows?

Comment: Looks like the same output to me.